# No error is thrown on inexistant table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I must miss something but I have a very strange behaviour with PDO (MySQL).

```
$req = null;
try {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO inexistant_table (idmember) VALUES(:idmember)';
    $req = $db->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindParam(':idmembre', $_SESSION['ID']);
    $req->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'exception';
}

if( !$req ) {
    echo 'false';
}
echo 'success';
```

Then I don't get any error, it only prints 'success'. Any idea?

**EDIT:** `$db->errorCode()` returns 00000.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858

Comment: You've made a typo: `VALUES(:idmember)` and using `(':idmembre',` change it to `(':idmember',`

Comment: Use `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened

Comment: ^--« My work is done. No need to thank me. It's a "thankless" job anyway.

Comment: Yes, it works. I don't get why that's not the default behaviour. Thank you, even if you don't accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outcome is explained as such,

#### Exceptions are *not* enabled - no "exception"

To enable exceptions, as per Fred -ii-'s comment, thanks! ;-)

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

(Also see [Reference - frequently asked questions about PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo?lq=1))

#### The wrong value is being checked - no "false"

The `$req` variable represents the prepared statement object, not the *result* of such executing such a statement. Compare with the following that checks the result.

```
$result = $req->execute();
// ..
if (!$result) { /* fail! */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention. I will +1 and get OP to accept as the correct answer just so we can close this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the other bug. Going to close this when SO let me.